# Elasticsearch wildcard query with spaces

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm trying to do a wildcard query with spaces. It easily matches the words on term basis but not on field basis.

I've read the documentation which says that I need to have the field as not_analyzed but with this type set, it returns nothing.

This is the mapping with which it works on term basis:

```
{
  "denshop" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "products" : {
        "properties" : {
          "code" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "price" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "url" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the mapping with which the exact same query returns nothing:

```
{
  "denshop" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "products" : {
        "properties" : {
          "code" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "price" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "url" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query is here:

`curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:9200/denshop/products/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"wildcard":{"name":"*test*"}}}'`

Response with the `not_analyzed` property:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Response without not_analyzed:

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
    ...
```

**EDIT: Adding requested info**

Here is the list of documents:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "denshop",
      "_type" : "products",
      "_id" : "3L1",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "Testovací produkt 2",
        "code" : "",
        "price" : 500,
        "url" : "http://www.denshop.lh/damske-obleceni/testovaci-produkt-2/"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "denshop",
      "_type" : "products",
      "_id" : "4L1",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "id" : 4,
        "name" : "Testovací produkt 3",
        "code" : "",
        "price" : 666,
        "url" : "http://www.denshop.lh/damske-obleceni/testovaci-produkt-3/"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "denshop",
      "_type" : "products",
      "_id" : "2L1",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Testovací produkt",
        "code" : "",
        "price" : 500,
        "url" : "http://www.denshop.lh/damske-obleceni/testovaci-produkt/"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "denshop",
      "_type" : "products",
      "_id" : "5L1",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "id" : 5,
        "name" : "Testovací produkt 4",
        "code" : "",
        "price" : 666,
        "url" : "http://www.denshop.lh/damske-obleceni/testovaci-produkt-4/"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "denshop",
      "_type" : "products",
      "_id" : "6L1",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "id" : 6,
        "name" : "Testovací produkt 5",
        "code" : "",
        "price" : 666,
        "url" : "http://www.denshop.lh/tricka-tilka-tuniky/testovaci-produkt-5/"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Without the `not_analyzed` it returns with this:

`curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:9200/denshop/products/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"wildcard":{"name":"*testovací*"}}}'`

But not with this (notice the space before asterisk):

`curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:9200/denshop/products/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"wildcard":{"name":"*testovací *"}}}'`

When I add the `not_analyzed` to mapping, it returns no hits no matter what I put in the wildcard query.

Comment: What documents doesn't match and it should? Please, give an example.

Comment: Updated the question with requested data.

Comment: Your documents have uppercase letters and with `not_analyzed` they will be indexed like that. When you search for `testovaci` (meaning lowercase letters) of course it will not match the uppercase `Testovaci`.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to let it match that field case insensitive? Or I can have only one of the two features?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a custom analyzer that should lowercase the text. Then in your search query, before passing the text to it **have it lowercased in your client application**.

To, also, keep the original analysis chain, I've added a sub-field to your `name` field that will use the custom analyzer.

```
PUT /denshop
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "keyword_lowercase": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "products": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "lowercase": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "keyword_lowercase"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the query will work on the sub-field:

```
GET /denshop/products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "name.lowercase": "*testovací *"
    }
  }
}
```